# Difference between pager and notifications

Tags: wear-os

I am not really understanding what's the difference between using a notification to build a ui where you can perform an action (click on button or display a card) and using the `GridViewPager` to do that.

I am creating an app where you can perform actions with a button (following the spec of google, on action/button per page). I am using the `GridViewPager` to do so. But looking at the samples that google provides and looking at the different wear apps that I could find, it looks like a lot of the applications have the same design : buttons with a blue background circle, provided by the Notification class.

In which case should I use the GridViewPager or the notifications?